# Not seeing updated SSIS variables

Tags: variables, ssis, task

In my SSIS package (VS 2008) I have a couple of ReadWrite variables (package-level) that I am setting inside the script task.
When I debug the task, I can see that the variables are, in fact, getting set.
However, when I exit the task and look at the Variables window, or in the Package Explorer, those variables still have the default (blank) values.  Why???

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

the variable values shown in the Variables window only show what the values will be when the package execution begins.  If these change during execution, these are not reflected, as the default values will remain so (that is, the defaults!) for the next execution.  Hope that makes sense!  As you say, the values do actually change when you check them when debugging.

Comment: Thank you!  So if I undestand correctly, the values change only while the package is executing.  When it's done, the values go back to defaults, correct?   I am used to work with DTS packages, and there I could execute one task to set the variables (a script, for example), then go to project's properties, see what their values are, then run another task using those changed variables.   Is there a way to do something like that in SSIS??

Answer (score 0):

If you put in breakpoints, you can check the variable values at the time the breakpoint was hit.

Comment: I know how to check variables during execution time.  That's not what I was asking about.